# Camel Failover Load Balancer not failing over to next target if a Dead Letter Channel Error Handler is defined in the route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have defined a camel route using a failover load balancer like this:

```java
from(activemq:foo)
    .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(activemq:foo.dlq).onPrepareFailure(failureProcessor))
    .process(processor)
    .loadBalance()
        .failover(2, true, true)
            .to(activemq:queue1, activemq:queue2)
    .end();
```

With the above-defined route, if delivery to queue1 fails, the exception is handled by the error handler and message is put directly into foo.dlq without load balancer failing over to the next target.

How do I define a route:
Which should failover to all the routes and if delivery to all of them fails (fails entirely), it should then send the control to error handler which should put the message to DLQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised.
I have just run the following test (in Camel 3.9) - with 2 dummy http endpoints:

```
from("timer://demo?period=60s")
    .errorHandler( deadLetterChannel("log:DLQ") )
    .log("Run")
    .loadBalance().failover(2, false, false)
        .to("direct:node1")
        .to("direct:node2")
    .end()
    .log("success");

from("direct:node1")
    .errorHandler( noErrorHandler() )
    .log("Attempt on node#1")
    .to("http://localhost:8881/ws");

from("direct:node2")
    .errorHandler( noErrorHandler() )
    .log("Attempt on node#2")
    .to("http://localhost:8882/ws");
```

And here is the output:

```
INFO  | route1                         | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Run
INFO  | route2                         | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Attempt on node#1
INFO  | route3                         | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Attempt on node#2
INFO  | DLQ                            | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
```

You clearly see that there is one attempt on each node, and the exchange finally goes to the DLQ

If i enable inheritErrorHandler, the output is now:

```
INFO  | route1                         | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Run
INFO  | route2                         | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Attempt on node#1
INFO  | DLQ                            | Camel (Test) thread #0 - t | Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: null, Body: [Body is null]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. Also, good that you mentioned the camel version. It was really a camel version issue. We are using 2.17.3 in our project which was not handling it the same way. I have upgraded to the latest version of Camel 2 (2.25.3) and this works exactly as described by you.

Comment: Glad you manage to solve your problem. Yes, upgrading the dependencies to a more recent version is very often a good idea when facing unexpected behaviours ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should turn `inheritErrorHandler` (2nd param) to off in your load balancer, ie:

```
.loadBalance()
   .failover(2, false, true)
```

This way, any failure on one of the two nodes gets propagated to the loadBalancer processor rather than to the DLQ.

But if the **whole** loadbalancing process fails (that is: if **both** nodes fail), the DLQ will be kicked in.

Hint: if you indent your code, the propagation logic is a bit more clear:

```
from("...")
  .errorHandler(...)
  .loadBalance().failover(2, false, true) // level 1
    .to("...") // level 2
    .to("...") // level 2
  .end();
```

You have two identation levels; each level having its own error handling:

- errors of level 2 are managed by the load balancer
- errors of level 1 are managed by the DLQ

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. If I set the flag "inheritErrorHandler" to false, the failover load balancer never propagates the error to the error handler, instead, the error is propagated back to the client and I end up losing the message. It never reaches DLQ. Any more pointers here? Thanks for your help!!